# What actually is the problem growing stone fruits into tropics?

Tags: peaches, plums, hardiness-zone, apricots, nectarines

I am experimenting to grow low-chill stone fruits namely peaches var."Florida Sun" and plums var. "Black Amber" into Zone 13 tropics. I know that they aren't recommended for Zone 13 or hot tropics. But I wonder what will be outcome of such an experiment? Will the plants simply die due to tropic heats? Will they be less productive? Will they live for a cycle and then fail to budbreak? Will they need Hydrogen Cyanamide (Dormex) or Paclobutrazol?

P.s. I am not planning to grow them in air conditioned microclimate as also not aiming for a marketable produce. Has anyone conducted such an experiment and can enlighten me about the same?

Comment: Supposedly they wont set fruit. I will have to Google.

Comment: I appreciate your points on outcome. Much Thanks! ✨Also, there's not plenty of literature available on google or even google scholar, being frowned by reddit communities and lack of articles is what brought me here. @RohitGupta

Comment: Low-chill is not "no chill" - without adequate time at temperature, they will never think winter has come, and therefore won't flower in spring, since they won't know when that is.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I appreciate your inputs and I am aware of difference among low-chill and no chill. However, my premise of understanding is "why or why won't they flower?". After all, Chill Hours isn't an exact science, it is a mere possibility to consider to overlook what plants have better chance to fruit in certain conditions.

Comment: Not exactly the same, but more-or-less on topic - I have a Cherry tree of some description in my garden - and I live in Zone 9B (I believe).  The tree flowers and gets a few tiny berries which drop off.  It produced more berries this year then normal - possibly because we had a very cool, wet summer - but nothing that came close to fully fruiting.  As a reference, I have peaches and plum trees which have no problem fruiting.

Comment: I thus expect you would get lots of leaves but no flowering - let alone fruit set - I don't think you really get a winter in zone 13.

Comment: @davidgo The answer (comment) I was expecting. Thanks a ton!✨ And yeah! You're correct on the part, we don't get any winters at all.